# Converting the units and values in cells to a standard unit

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have to interpret data for scientific reports. We report the data all in the same units. However, the lab sends the data in different units. For example the lab may send the results in ug (micrograms) and we need to convert it to mg (milligrams). I would therefore like to know how to make a macro that you can apply to a column or row to convert the results (i.e. divide the result number by 1000).

The issue I have is that the data is normally mixed up, with different units in the same column. Therefore, the macro only needs to be applied to the results that have the incorrect unit (i.e. only the results already in ug need to be converted to mg).

As my data will often comprise thousands of rows, it really needs to be a macro so that I can highlight a row and run the macro. It would then replace the contents of the 'reported results' cells with the revised figures and update the 'result units' cells with the corrected unit as well.

An example of the data I receive is as follows:

[image: Example of Lab Data Received]

If anyone has any ideas I would be really grateful.

Comment: I can suggest you Macro will convert all values from Microgram to Miligram except the values has < sign. But I can suggest you  a formula  for those values (<1) to convert from ug to mg,,just confirm will it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple, yet robust and smart, macro that normalises micrograms to milligrams:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <any standard module>
' Version    : 0.1.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1333314/763880
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Public Sub NormaliseUnits()
       Dim ¡ As Long

  Dim rngTarget As Range
  For Each rngTarget In Selection.Areas
    'Minimise the number of cells to be processed
    Set rngTarget = Intersect(rngTarget, rngTarget.Parent.UsedRange)
    If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit For 'Nothing to do as the mimimised Area doesn't contain any data
    ' Expand the minimised target to include the previous column:
    If rngTarget.Column > 1 Then
      Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Resize(ColumnSize:=rngTarget.Columns.Count + 1)
    End If
    ' Expand the minimised target to include the next column:
    If rngTarget.Column + rngTarget.Columns.Count - 1 < Columns.Count Then
      Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Resize(ColumnSize:=rngTarget.Columns.Count + 1)
    End If
    ' Loop through all cells (skipping the first column) looking for a "ug" to fix
    Dim rngRow As Range
    For Each rngRow In rngTarget.Rows
      For ¡ = 2 To rngRow.Columns.Count
        If rngRow.Cells(¡) = "ug" _
        And rngRow.Cells(¡ - 1) <> vbNullString _
        Then
          Dim strValue As String: strValue = CStr(rngRow.Cells(¡ - 1).Value2)
          Dim strLessThan As String: strLessThan = vbNullString
          If InStr("<>", Left$(strValue, 1)) Then
            strLessThan = Left$(strValue, 1)
            strValue = Mid$(strValue, 2)
          End If
          If IsNumeric(strValue) Then
            rngRow.Cells(¡ - 1).Value2 = strLessThan & CStr(CDbl(strValue) / 1000)
            rngRow.Cells(¡) = "mg"
          End If
        End If
      Next ¡
    Next rngRow
  Next rngTarget

End Sub
```

It's actually so smart, you can select anything, entire rows, entire columns, single cells, even dis-contiguous ranges, and it will find and normalise all appropriate values/units.

**Notes:**

- Values preceded by a `<` *or* `>` are correctly normalised
- If the value is blank or not a number, both it and the unit remain unchanged